# Function to determine if a number is repeated in a year is true or false, seems to not like the 1800's?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a function whether a number repeats, it seems like the function works most of the time but not reliably. I'm not sure what the problem with my code is, code follows:

```
def repeat?(year)

  y_arr = year.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)

  y_arr.each do |i|
    y_arr.each do |j|
      if (i != j) && (y_arr[i] == y_arr[j])
        return true
      end
    end
  end
  return false

end


puts(repeat?(1702))
puts(repeat?(1997))
puts(repeat?(2001))
puts(repeat?(1859))
```

output for the above ->

```
false
true
true
true (should be false?)
```

changed code to:

```
def repeat?(year)

  y_arr = year.to_s.split('').map(&:to_i)

  for i in 0..y_arr.length
    for j in 0..y_arr.length
      if (i != j) && (y_arr[i] == y_arr[j])
        return true
      end
    end
  end
  return false

end
```

Works now! Thanks for your responses

Comment: [`Array#each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-each) passes each _value_ of the array, not each index, so `y_arr[i]` is going to  be meaningless.

Comment: Define what you mean by a number repeating.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it much more complex than it needs to be. This can be done with a one-liner.

```
/(\d)\1+/ =~ number.to_s
```

The `\1+` is known as a backreference in regex. It references what is captured between the parentheses which in this case is a digit.

This will find repeated digits.

Comment: If the purpose is just to tell whether there is a match, then using `scan` is very bad. Also, under that purpose, `+` is redundant.

Comment: I understand. I was able to find a better solution in the documentation. I used `=~` and it works now

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done by checking whether digits are unique or not.

```
def repeat?(year)
    not (year.to_s.chars == year.to_s.chars.uniq)
end

puts(repeat?(1702))
#=> false
puts(repeat?(1997))
#=> true
puts(repeat?(2001))
#=> true
puts(repeat?(1800))
#=> true
```